# How is Fuel needed to be consumed calculated when MTOM and Actual Mass is known

Tags: fuel, performance-calculation

I'm practicing for my EASA PPL(A) exams and one of the questions I came across looks like this:

> How much taxi fuel must be consumed before take-off to reduce the
> aircraft mass to the maximum take-off mass?
>
> Maximum ramp mass (MRM): 1150 kg
>  Actual ramp mass: 1148 kg
> Maximum take-off mass (MTOM): 1145 kg (1,00 P.)
>
> Possible answers:
>
> - 2L
> - 3L
> - 5L
> - 4L

Now, my thinking was Fuel needed to be consumed = Actual ramp mass - MTOM => 3L

But it seems the correct answer is 4L. I don't understand why.

Comment: This looks like an ATPL question. Is this really on the EASA private pilot exam?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your thinking is correct, the fuel needed to be consumed is indeed the actual ramp mass - MTOM. That results in 3 **kg** of fuel.

What you forgot is to convert the weight into a volume (note that the answers use litres). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avgas) Avgas has a density of 0.72 kg/L, so the answer is:

$$ \frac{1148 \, \text{kg} - 1145 \, \text{kg}}{0.72 \, \text{kg/L}} \approx 4.17 \, \text{L} \approx 4 \, \text{L} $$

Comment: It is a good question! Converting between volume and weight is extremely important to get right in aviation. One example that comes to mind is the "Gimli Glider" accident (see wikipedia or youtube).

Comment: (Very much non-pilot here) If the exact answer is slightly above 4, and the only answer alternatives given are 2, 3, 4, and 5, shouldn’t the correct answer be 5, since burning 4 liters still leaves you 0.17*0.72 ≈ 0.12 kg overweight? Admittedly, 0.12 kg is probably within the measurement error, but I would expect that one would want any rounding to go in a "safe" direction.